# Using url-expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-el

I have a spring integration configured to build a url from a property and some variables:

```
    <int-http:outbound-gateway
            url="${pdf.url}?id={id}&amp;version={version}"
            request-factory="int.http.requestFactory"
            http-method="GET"
            transfer-cookies="false"
            header-mapper="fTokenHeaderMapper"
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String" >
        <int-http:uri-variable name="id" expression="payload.id"/>
        <int-http:uri-variable name="version" expression="payload.version"/>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Now I want to change it so that the server part (pdf.url) could be changed on the fly and not only on startup. To achieve that I have changed from 'url' to 'url-expression' and something like this:

```
    <int-http:outbound-gateway
            url-expression="@configurationService.getConfiguration('pdf.url')?id={id}&amp;version={version}"
            request-factory="int.http.requestFactory"
            http-method="GET"
            transfer-cookies="false"
            header-mapper="fTokenHeaderMapper"
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String" >
        <int-http:uri-variable name="id" expression="payload.id"/>
        <int-http:uri-variable name="version" expression="payload.version"/>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

This line seems to work:

```
url-expression="@configurationService.getConfiguration('pdf.url')"
```

But how do I include the variables in a similar way as the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the big height I'd move that URI variables part to the `configurationService.getConfiguration()`, too. It will be more cleaner to read the XML config.

From other side the `url-expression` is a SpEL runtime expression. So, any its part which should not be executable, must be as **literal**:

```
url-expression="@configurationService.getConfiguration('pdf.url') + '?id={id}&amp;version={version}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is only read once during startup, so you can't change the value of `pdf.url` during runtime and expect that it'll change dynamically.